# boto dynamodb conditional projectionexpression in query/scan alternative

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am a beginner in Python.
I am trying to fetch query and scan results from dynamodb. As per the syntax, I am able to fetch the results using

```
        response = table.get_item(
            Key={
                pk_key: pk_value,
            },
            ExpressionAttributeNames={'#key_1': 'key_1'},
            ProjectionExpression='#key_1'
        )
```

But I need to reuse my code so as to handle situations where ProjectionExpression/ExpressionAttributeNames is not required. Please suggest if I can handle this apart from writing an overloaded function for each different scenario as in that case number of functions will shoot up.

Comment: Searching with `table.get_item(Key={pk_key: pk_value})` is stil quite brief and reusable. What kind of result do you want to end up with? How more reusable, I mean?

Comment: The results are good. The problem is : In a few cases I will need to use projected expression in my scan  and sometimes I won't. similarly, sometimes I might need to use ExpressionAttributeNames and sometimes I won't. I want to avoid a situation creating multiple combinations of overloaded functions.